# Java to find if an array is a subset of another

Tags: java

Im having trouble to find out if a specific amount of numbers is in another array.The first array generates 10 random numbers and in the second array the user guesses 5 numbers.Im trying to find out if the user guessed any sequences.I used for loops to find out if numbers of user input is in any of the numbers from 1-5 in the array of 10 , if not it will check numbers 2-6 and so on.
For example, if the program had the following winning numbers:
23 56 67 **06 43 22** 59 24 90 66 and user entered: 01 **06 43 22** 89.
I keep getting index out of bounds.How do I fix this ?

```
    // to check if user guessed a sequence
    
    boolean guessed = false;
    int counter = 0;
    int i , j = 0;
    
    for (i = 4; i < numbers.length; i++) {    // users numbers
        
        for ( j = 4; j < lottery.length; j++) {  // first 5 numbers from array 
            
            if ( lottery[i] == numbers[j]) {
                break;
            }
            if ( j == i) {
                guessed = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: any reason why you are starting the loop at 4?

Comment: Do you mean always three numbers have to be in sequence in both the arrays?

Comment: So basically I want to check if the user guessed 2,3 ,4 or all numbers(in the same order) of the lottery array

Comment: I started the loop at 4 because I want to check if the users  numbers match the first  5 numbers in the lottery array, I keep getting index out of bound all the time

Comment: You have reversed your indexes.  Your outer loop checks `i < numbers.length`, so you should be looking at `numbers[i]`.  Similarly, your inner loop checks `j < lottery.length`, so you should be looking at `lottery[j]`.

Comment: I tried this but I want the answer to be true ONLY if the users numbers are guessed in the same order but this gives me true if ANY of the 4 numbers are in the array.Im trying to find the simplest way to see if the 5 numbers are in the first set of 5 numbers of the (lottery) array , if not it would move to the next set , for example if lottery numbers are 11 32 45 43 12 65 76 89 84 30  , It should first check from 11 - 12 , then 32 - 65 and so on

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a method similar to `String::indexOf` should be implemented in this task for the arrays trying to find an index of a subarray `int indexOf(int[] search, int[] input)`.

Also, it might be needed to look for *all possible subarrays* of the `search` subarray (`lottery`).  Thus, the mentioned method should be extended to look for a subrange of the `search` argument: `int indexOf(int[] search, int[] input)`

Straightforward implementation would be:

```java
static int indexOf(int search[], int from, int to, int[] input) {
    if (null == search || null == input || search.length > input.length) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0, n = input.length - (to - from); i <= n; i++) {
        boolean found = true;
        for (int j = from; found && j < to; j++) {
            if (input[i + j - from] != search[j]) {
                found = false;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The widths and appropriate indexes `from` / `to` of the search subranges can be generated as follows (from the entire length of `lottery` to 2):

```
int[] numbers = {23, 56, 67, 06, 43, 22, 59, 24, 90, 66};
int[] lottery = {01, 06, 43, 22, 89};

for (int n = lottery.length; n > 1; n--) {
    for (int m = 0; m <= lottery.length - n; m++) {
        int ix = indexOf(lottery, m, m + n, numbers);
        if (ix > -1) {
            System.out.printf("Found subarray %s, width=%d from: %d to %d ",
                    Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(lottery, m, m + n)), n, m, m + n - 1);
            System.out.printf("at index: %d%n", ix);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Found subarray [6, 43, 22], width=3 from: 1 to 3 at index: 3
Found subarray [6, 43], width=2 from: 1 to 2 at index: 3
Found subarray [43, 22], width=2 from: 2 to 3 at index: 4
```

A more efficient implementation would use [Knuth - Morris - Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) to bypass recurrent checks of the same values in the input array.

Comment: Where and how you try to create it?  It is just a method that should be invoked from static `main` method, as shown in [this demo](https://ideone.com/llFjHJ)